# Explanation of the Python itertools.product() implementation?

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

**How does this Python magic work?**

The code in question comes from the Python `itertools.product` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
def product(*args):
    pools = map(tuple, args)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

***Note***: Yes, I understand this is not the actual implementation. Also, I have removed the `repeat` arg to simplify the code and focus the discussion

I understand **what** the above code does (its output), but I'm looking for an explanation of **how** it works. I'm already familiar with list comprehensions, including nested `for`s.

This is specifically puzzling:

```py
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

I've attempted to convert the above code into a series of `for` loops without any list comprehension, but I fail to get correct results. This kind of algorithm generally requires recursion to handle an arbitrary number of input sets. Hence my confusion that the above code seems to do this iteratively.

Can anyone explain how this code works?

Comment: It is kind of doing it recursively, result get reassign in each iteration of the loop

Comment: Note, no algorithm **ever requires** a recursive solution. Any recursive algorithm can be converted to use iteration with a stack.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Of course, but in this case I didn't realize the `results` list is being used for that purpose, similar to the way a stack is used in an iterative tree traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list-comprehension converted into a regular for-loop, if that helps you understand:

```
def product_nocomp(*args):
    pools = map(tuple, args)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        _temp = []
        for x in result:
            for y in pool:
                _temp.append(x + [y])
        result = _temp
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

And here's some illuminating `print`'s:

```
In [9]: def product_nocomp(*args):
   ...:     pools = list(map(tuple, args))
   ...:     result = [[]]
   ...:     print("Pools: ", pools)
   ...:     for pool in pools:
   ...:         print(result, end=' | ')
   ...:         _temp = []
   ...:         for x in result:
   ...:             for y in pool:
   ...:                 _temp.append(x + [y])
   ...:         result = _temp
   ...:         print(result)
   ...:     for prod in result:
   ...:         yield tuple(prod)
   ...:

In [10]: list(product_nocomp(range(2), range(2)))
Pools:  [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
[[]] | [[0], [1]]
[[0], [1]] | [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
Out[10]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

So, for every tuple in the pool, it goes through every sublist in the intermediate result, and adds every item to the sublist for every item in the current pool. Note, it is *creating new lists*.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you! The part I was missing was the `_temp` variable within the outermost loop.

Comment: @djsmith yes, a list comprehension lets you not use an intermediate variable while you build up the new list.